# SQLCMD utility generate rejected rows to flat file

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd, sqlbulkcopy

Currently I am using SQLCMD Utility to load the CSV data to SQL Server. Below is my command which was executed in command prompt to load the data:

```
sqlcmd -Usa -Pxxx -S192.168.1.223,49546 -dlocal -i"/test.sql" -o"/test.log"
```

I have also copied my `test.sql` file contents for your reference:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON 
BULK INSERT test FROM 
"\\192.168.1.223\test.csv"
WITH
(
MAXERRORS = 1000000,
CODEPAGE = 1251,
FIELDTERMINATOR = '~%',
ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'
)
GO
SELECT CONVERT(varchar,@@ROWCOUNT) + ' rows affected'
GO
```

The insert operation is working fine with the above process. But my concern is, in case of any errors due to data type or data length the row is rejected and I am unable to trace the particular row.

Each time I have to look at the log file for the rejected row number and the data file to check the corresponding row.

Is there any option to generate the error/rejected row to another file, as like we have in **ORACLE - SQLPLUS** Utility to generate **bad** file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the option your are looking for is not in sqlcmd, but in [`BULK INSERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql):

> ERRORFILE ='file_name'
>
> Specifies the file used to collect rows that have formatting errors and cannot be converted to an OLE DB rowset. These rows are copied into this error file from the data file "as is."

Comment: Thanks etsa, Can you help me how to add "ERRORFILE " syntax in Bulk insert. Please illustrate with the above sql script. Thanks

Comment: do some tries using MS documentation and, if you have any problems, post your new script in your question.

Comment: After adding ERRORFILE ='file_name' in sql script file, the error records are created in another flat file. It solved now !

Comment: Nice.  You could also be interested to investigate influence of MAXERRORS value on record inserted in ERRORFILE...